# Funny Numbers :D

Tags: code-golf, string, math, number

The task is to calculate the average "funniness" of a given number given the following scoring system:

- 1 point for each "420" in it
- 2 points for each "69" in it
- 3 points if its a palindrome (doesn't count if it's just a single digit)
- 4 points if it has (not for each) "800813"
- 5 points for ending in "420"
- 6 points for ending in "69"

Then, divide that total score by the number of digits in the number (round to the nearest tenth)

Test Cases:

- **96942024969: 1.3** (14p/11 digits, 1p for one "420", 4p for two "69"s, 3p since its an palindome, 6p for ending in "69")
- **800813800813: 0.3** (4p/12 digits for having "800813")
- **0: 0** (0p/1 digit)
- **420: 2** (6p/3 digits, 1p for one "420", 5p for ending in "420")
- **2435083240587: 0** (0p/13 digits)

Answers are ranked by lowest program size.

Comment: Welcome to CGCC! This question seems not to have an objective scoring criterion. Are we trying to minimize program size, or something else?

Comment: Thanks, yeah I was going for minimum program size. :)

Comment: You say 8008135 gives +4, but then in the test cases it's 800813. Which one is correct?

Comment: @Joseph Would you mind saying as much in the question? You should probably also add the [tag:code-golf] tag.

Comment: oops im stupid thanks yeah thats a typo @CommandMaster

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean by a number being an anagram?

Comment: wow i made a lot of mistakes in this my bad I thought I checked well, I meant an anagram to be the same front and back but that is not

Comment: Can a number with trailing zeroes be an anagram?

Comment: You mean palindrome not anagram, I think

Comment: I should've clarified that palindromes*** (thanks @NickKennedy) should have more than one digit, and so therefore nothing with a trailing zero could be an palindrome since it couldn't have 0s before it. ("00100" doesnt make sense as a number)

Comment: So... The funniest number would be 69? (6+2)/2= 4 in funny scale :P

Comment: [indeed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hFYGR.png)

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 35 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
Ž¥ú2ä©¢IÂQIg≠*I•CΘ=•åI®Å¿)˜ā*OIg/1.ò
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f//6N5DSw/vMjq85NDKQ4s8DzcFeqY/6lyg5fmoYZHzuRm2QOrwUs9D6w63HtqveXrOkUYtf890fUO9w5v@/7c0szQxMjAyAdIA) or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/V9Waa@k8KhtkoKSfeX/o3sPLT28y@jwkkMrDy2qPNwUWJn@qHOBVuWjhkXO52bYAqnDSysPrTvcemi/5uk5x7b5V6brG@od3vRf53@0kqWZpYmRgZEJkFbSUbIwMLAwNIaQQK4BEANlgaSRibGpgYWxkYmBqYW5UiwA).

**Explanation:**

```python
Ž¥ú2ä©¢    # Verify the first two rules:
Ž¥ú        #  Push compressed integer 42069
   2ä      #  Split it into two parts: [420,69]
     ©     #  Store it in variable `®` (without popping)
      ¢    #  Count how many times each occur in the (implicit) input-string
IÂQIg≠*    # Verify the third rule:
I          #  Push the input again
 Â         #  Bifurcate it; short for Duplicate & Reverse copy
  Q        #  Pop both and check if they're the same (aka it's a palindrome)
   Ig      #  Push the input-length
     ≠     #  Check that it's NOT 1 (0 if 1; 1 if >=2)
      *    #  Multiply them together
I•CΘ=•å    # Verify the fourth rule:
I          #  Push the input again
 •CΘ=•     #  Push compressed integer 800813
      å    #  Check if the input contains this number as substring
I®Å¿       # Verify the fifth and sixth rules:
I          #  Push the input yet again
 ®         #  Push pair [420,69] from variable `®`
  Å¿       #  Check whether the input ends with either of these two
)          # Wrap all items on the stack into a list
 ˜         # Flatten the list of pairs and loose values to a single list
  ƶ        # Multiply each value in the list by its 1-based index
   O       # Then sum the list together
    Ig/    # Divide it by the input-length
       1.ò # Round it to 1 decimal after the period
           # (after which the result is output implicitly)
```

[See this 05AB1E tip of mine (section *How to compress large integers?*)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166851/52210) to understand why `Ž¥ú` is `42069` and `•CΘ=•` is `800813`.

Answer (score 4):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 89 bytes

```
{round (m:g/420/+2*m:g/69/+3*($_>9&&$_
eq.flip)+4*?/800813/+5*?/420$/+6*?/69$/)/.comb,.1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYzLCoMwFET3/YqLBFFTvDGvJqXaTwl9mFLQai1diPjtaYqbmcPAmbGdOh36GVIPdVim4fu6Q9YfHyg5Q8qLP2qLVBQZcY1NU@J27bv03XPMqSzOaBgzlUCqIkeHINWRtCWYY3kb@uu@rNbwucyQEAd1A4sH4tYE/DDByWobJS5jw/a0JTCIO3ApFDOCS6bMoQk/)

Regex-driven, conveniently.

Answer (score 4):

## Excel, 188 bytes

```
=LET(
    a,800813,
    b,{69,420},
    c,A1,
    d,LEN(c),
    ROUND(
        SUM(
            MMULT(d-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(c,b,"")),1/{1;3}),
            3*(d>1)*(c=0+CONCAT(MID(c,d-SEQUENCE(d)+1,1))),
            4*(FIND(a,c&a)<d),
            (0+RIGHT(c,{2,3})=b)*{6,5}
        )/d,
        1
    )
)
```

Input in cell `A1`.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>136</s> 131 bytes

*-5 from [@Jonathan Allan](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/53748/jonathan-allan)*

```python
lambda s:"%0.1f"%(((c:=s.count)(m:="420")+2*c("69")+3*(s[:1]<s*c(s[::-1]))+4*("800813"in s)+5*(e:=s.endswith)(m)+6*e("69"))/len(s))
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY5BasMwEEX3OYUYCMzYTirLsiuL-iSuF6ljEUEih0ihZJ1jdGMo7Z16m8rYm_l_Bub9__V7fYTT6KZv07z_3IPZqb_n-XD5OB6Y17Dl-9zAFhF73fh9P95dILzoBqTgQKlIeoSqjq5I0Lc67958PEWnd3lHlMoEQXGu8gKsY57SMsFhRg3u6D9tOEUapVUyLBh6OQ8OPdFapTXjjVkWX1uoqzqGChkVMrZSV3bc-TzmVlGELEquCiF5qV6h0xvGrjfrAtoMNGQGLdFmiZimRf8B)

A crappy solution, but a solution nonetheless.

Comment: Save three by counting occurrences of the reverse with `1<len(s)*c(s[::-1])`. Save another with `m:="420"`.

Comment: Actually, one more with `s[:1]<s*c(s[::-1])` instead.

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 302 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 37.75 bytes

```
⁺md69"₌vøEvO?₍λḂ⁼n₀>*;‡800813c$WfÞż∑$L/1∆W
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI9IiwiIiwi4oG6bWQ2OVwi4oKMdsO4RXZPP+KCjc674biC4oG8buKCgD4qO+KAoTgwMDgxM2MkV2bDnsW84oiRJEwvMeKIhlciLCIiLCI4MDA4MTM4MDA4MTMiXQ==)

Many more bytes added to handle single digits not being a palindrome.

Comment: [-1 bit](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyJB4biLPSIsIiIsIuKBum1kNjlcIuKCjHZPdsO4RT/igo3igKHhuILigbzigKHCu+KAolFywrtjJFdmw57FvOKIkeKCgCokTC/huZnigoAvIiwiIiwiOTY5NDIwMjQ5NjlcbjgwMDgxMzgwMDgxM1xuMFxuNDIwXG4yNDM1MDgzMjQwNTg3Il0=)

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES11), 136 bytes

```javascript
s=>~~([/420/g,/69/g,,800813,/420$/,/69$/].reduce((t,r,i)=>t-~i/3*~~s.match(r)?.length,s>9&[...s].reverse().join``==s)*30/s.length+.5)/10
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY9BasMwEEX3PYURoUiJopElO5UXcg8SCimO7Lg4FlhOl1r3Dt2Y0t6iF-ltKmNBwZ3FfBje_Pnz_tnbs5k-av11G-u9-nlzuvQeHyETHBoKhyJ0qjhXqaTzcAPzcANPbDDnW2UwHulAW6LLce9bkFvvHbs-j9UFD-SRdaZvxgt1ZXF_ZIy5ee3VDM5gwl5s259OWjuylRxcZHcsJ5DymOe7sr2znWGdbXCNUXEoQgiRBUVJQkgCkKRM3q2wJfDSUcT4f4wHj7-K2BoK99AaEmtIZDLnSoqM5-oBRaflh2la9Bc)

Comment: JavaScript (Node.js), 132 bytes: [`s=>~~([0,/420/g,/69/g,s>9&&[...s].reverse().join``,800813,/420$/,/69$/].reduce((t,r,i)=>t+i*~~s.match(r)?.length)*10/s.length+.5)/10`](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=ZY9BasMwEEX3PYURIUiJOhrLdiIv7B4kFFIc2XFxLLCULr3qLboxpT1GD9LbVKkFBXcWMwy8-f_P20dvTnp6r4vPq6vv1ferLcpxpAfkIpUoGi52ue-2zNfrAwDYRxj0ix6spgyeTdsfj1whqjj5PViJ28FK3KjTtdKUOj7wlhWl27abcbRweXLVmQ7sATrdN-7MNjEKG5YtZEzEGLJ83VWmt6bT0JmG1pTku9x7yNRPEkWMRUJEMSRLbM4zdxIw_I-h1_irgC0h70eWkFxCMk0yVIlMMVN7EpTmJ6Zpnj8)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL(Dyalog Unicode)](https://dyalog.com), 65 bytes <sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

```
1⍕≢÷⍨1⊥4⍸⍤⌽(1<≢×⊢≡⌽),(1∊'800813'⍷,),(,⍤⍉⍤↑'024' '96'(⊃,+/)⍤⍷¨⊂⍤⌽)
```

[Try it on APLgolf!](https://razetime.github.io/APLgolf/?h=AwA&c=M3zUO/VR56LD2x/1rjB81LXU5FHvjke9Sx717NUwtAFJTH/UtehR50KggKaOhuGjji51CwMDC0Nj9Ue923WAQjog1b2dILJtorqBkYm6grqlmbrGo65mHW19TbDs9kMrHnU1QYzVBAA&f=S1NQtzSzNDEyMDIB0upcaQrqFgYGFobGEBIsAJQF0xDSyMTY1MDC2MjEwNTCXB0A&i=AwA&r=tryapl&l=apl-dyalog&m=dfn&n=f)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 55 bytes

```
﹪%.1f∕⁺⁺ΣＥ⪪42069³⁺×⁺⁵κ¬⊟⪪θι×⊕κ№θι∧∧⊖Ｌθ⁼θ⮌θ³∧№θ800813⁴Ｌθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY9tC8IgFIX/igjBFSzWWtHoU1QfgopR/YGx3Upyuhfd3zftbYJeOOc5h2vxyNtC59K5rBXKwFGXVmqgo8n0RjnZil6UCJm03ee52AqOeQ2XWgoDNImjReq5GePk7V9FhV90zsnTyydtINO/RMOJYP5w8iH3qmixQmWwhEBvtFUD5YW1KiHcLQ7gAdXdPKAJ/q6xuexC4ow9th0GmYWNvuF/I11G0XI6o15Pgjm0MLZyLl2k/jdx4qcb9/IF) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
         Ｅ⪪42069³                                         Map over `420`,`69`
                  ×⁺⁵κ¬⊟⪪θι                               5 or 6 if ends with
                 ⁺                                        Plus
                           ×⊕κ№θι                         1 or 2 times count
                                 ∧∧⊖Ｌθ⁼θ⮌θ³               3 if palindrome
                                           ∧№θ800813⁴     4 if `800813`
      ⁺⁺Σ                                                 Take the sum
                                                    Ｌθ     Divide by length
﹪%.1f                                                       Round to `0.1`
                                                            Implicitly print
```

Previous <s>57</s> 56 byte solution:

```
﹪%.1f∕ΣＥ⟦№θ420№θ69∧⊖Ｌθ⁼θ⮌θ‹⁰№θ800813¬⊟⪪θ420¬⊟⪪θ69⟧×ι⊕κＬθ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bY7BCsIwEER/JQSEDURpqxSLJ7EeBBVRb@KhtKsNpknbtP39mIBSD56WnTfMTF5mba4zae2pFaqDgy56qYFOZuGDcpKKQRQIl76CQ1bDbaN7Z2o4oYsooIyTUYgT/69VASnmLVaoOixgj@rZldAwx7ZNn0njzWccsDXoZafv0RgIfrOWQbAM59TDo@7gpGu41FL8NP9HfgNjd06uokIDgpOdGre8Pm3fRYytrE3ixAVGC3ftdJBv) Link is to verbose version of code. Explanation:

```
         №θ420                                              Count of `420`s
              №θ69                                          Count of `69`s
                  ∧⊖Ｌθ⁼θ⮌θ                                  Is a palindrome
                          ‹⁰№θ800813                        Includes `800813`
                                    ¬⊟⪪θ420                 Ends with `420`
                                           ¬⊟⪪θ69           Ends with `69`
       Ｅ⟦                                        ⟧          Map over values
                                                  ×ι⊕κ      Multiply by index
      Σ                                                     Take the sum
     ∕                                                Ｌθ    Divide by length
﹪%.1f                                                       Round to `0.1`
                                                            Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Retina 0.8.2](https://github.com/m-ender/retina/wiki/The-Language/a950ad7d925ec9316e3e2fb2cf5d49fd15d23e3d), <s>205</s> <s>201</s> 197 bytes

```
(?=(.*?420)*)(?=(.*?69)*)(?=((.)+.?(?<-4>\4)+$(?(4)^))?)(?=(.*800813)?).+(?<=(420)?)(?<=(69)?)
$#1$*1$#2$*2$#3$*3$#5$*4$#6$*5$#7$*6/$.&$*
\d
$*
\G1
10$*
/(.+)\1
$1$&
r`.*(\3)*(\3{10})*/(1+)
$#2.$#1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LU5BjsIwDLz7G/Ei2xFpnKSllYAc@USFQIIDFw7V3lb79uKIXsYz9mjGy/P39b6vP3S5rVRPFKSWFFl4E8O0cQrsQ6V63JfzXNgjVSp8Za6bdYxx1GwyeHOdqMW0m1ELqQzoFEXRJZSELqNkdD1KQTeg9OgOKEOHYYcC8wMaXhQ0GukoeJ4VUHEHyy0IzZkb/Gn8Z@lIfYtPwSrWdRom607FJnyf@iJEsD2kkvs45lRiPx4@) Link includes test cases. Explanation:

```
(?=(.*?420)*)(?=(.*?69)*)(?=((.)+.?(?<-4>\4)+$(?(4)^))?)(?=(.*800813)?).+(?<=(420)?)(?<=(69)?)
$#1$*1$#2$*2$#3$*3$#5$*4$#6$*5$#7$*6/$.&$*
```

Work out how many times `420` and `69` appear, plus also record whether the input is a nontrivial palindrome, whether it contains 800813, and whether it ends with `420` or `69`, plus take its length in unary.

```
\d
$*
```

Convert the scores to unary individually; the length is unaffected, since it is already in unary.

```
\G1
10$*
/(.+)\1
$1$&
r`.*(\3)*(\3{10})*/(1+)
$#2.$#1
```

Divide the total score by the length, rounding to the nearest `0.1`, and converting to decimal.

Answer (score 1):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 123 bytes

```javascript
n=>([s=.5,/420/g,/69/g,n>9&&[...n].reverse().join``,800813,/420$/,/69$/].map((x,i)=>n.replace(x,y=>s+=i*10/n.length))|s)/10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZY1Ra4NAEITf@yvkCOGutbvrqYk@nH8kBCL2Yg12T7wQUuh/t5dECJh9mGXgm5lTfal9M3bD@ZPdl52OZmJTyZ03kMeYacI2xk0ZlKtyvd4BAO9htBc7eisVnFzHh0NcEBVJeg@s8BZY4R5@6kHKa9wpU3GIDH3d2OB/TeU/TPeeEDL0ltvzt1J/XmFCU@PYu95C71p5lKLclKFRZ@GLKFIqQowSSN8W2GP9oWLG6BWj0PG8GVtCYU8sIb2EdJbmVKQ6o7zYirlp@gc)

Answer (score 1):

## [Scala](http://www.scala-lang.org/), 289 bytes

Port of [@97.100.97.109's Python answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/265540/110802) in Scala.

Thanks to @Joseph's help to correct the scala code.

---

Golfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZZBNawIxEIbv/RUhSEl0SfdLu1qyYJHSg0KplB5ljaOmpFnZiVIQf/s2W21X6CHk8L4zPM@gKkxRl8sPUI7MCHw5sCsk493ueHNDDoUhakTmrtJ2I/NJuV8aILJGmT/qzQSU/iwMYyjQ6JWvsIQLVe6tYwspaRqHlPfibhvH1/Fg6NOky/SaoZQoKjhAhXCLwoDduG0e8YiAQSAh7/20/LB1hbbIaBaGWZRQzkn61@mfd4nG4F27LTsTXG0Z/Gs0EG2BC1eeJe9@KbhAcHN/JWBR0EqLV@/ROM3KFYjn8fRp8fbSjtcPU42O0eFg6Bni1P80uEBf0AMa@tcQBjROk36YJXEa9rN7ysW6rKBQW6ZlvvOnd8YypB1NRqRzVEzzk4c@1d8)

```scala
s=>BigDecimal((s.sliding(3).count(_=="420")+2*s.sliding(2).count(_=="69")+3*(if(s==s.reverse&s.length>1)1 else 0)+(if(s.contains("800813")) 4 else 0)+5*(if(s.endsWith("420"))1 else 0)+6*(if(s.endsWith("69"))1 else 0)).toDouble/s.length).setScale(1,BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
```

Ungolfed version. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNda9tAEHzvrxhECKc6lWXJVm1TFxxC6UMCJSb0oZSgSGv70vOd0Z1CS/Bvd1cfUazQgpB0q52bvZmRzVKVHo/m4ZEyh5tUatBvRzq3WO73eH4H8JXTGtyYlSp1tMpMQcLOsXKF1Bt/jitTPijCom4HnlKFzJTajaOQizawSubcKWI/qOviHosFPP7s@X1EMusBoj4gmZ3071MldV6YHV0aXVrGyTWErRptUNATFZZwfs4LRXrjtviMkY8RSHE97NNOw3A6iusthGVK7VgIK7ym7vk@xi0OGA6xzB9L6yiHM6jekG0p@1XxvyBYRGmdBcvptgRbK9Vxsrx89t7YQSX5d@m2opHlH5NyRzL7H6iS5gTTgZxxqaodY1BnygAR3neKDxDz6q2eg540A0y453TwAZKm0g7VcF7KzRVlcpcq8UodONNGZNjZ4QeW3IpDRWJ0cQILbpm1Mv/G5BR8XV5/ub/75nc7MMmhYjLsbyFzqqO5Y7dEWmw4k8uiSP/8aJL5k6N5p6XrBVPqfekqBa/ZIOHNkhmfKBrz07t4sa81kddhdasM4Uc0jifhNI7G4WT6sQ3i2hQQEp8@tPv6LROw5wmc0sJ6ZxJznD2/@X@kf2j3ONRnOhyPfwE)

```scala
object Main extends App {
  
  def calculateScore(s: String): Double = {
    val count420 = s.sliding(3).count(_ == "420")
    val count69 = s.sliding(2).count(_ == "69")
    val palindromeBonus = if (s == s.reverse && s.length > 1) 1 else 0
    val count800813 = if(s.contains("800813")) 4 else 0  // Adjusted to just check if "800813" exists in the string
    val end420Bonus = if (s.endsWith("420")) 1 else 0
    val end69Bonus = if (s.endsWith("69")) 1 else 0

    val totalScore = count420 + 2 * count69 + 3 * palindromeBonus + count800813 + 5 * end420Bonus + 6 * end69Bonus

    BigDecimal(totalScore.toDouble / s.length).setScale(1, BigDecimal.RoundingMode.HALF_UP).toDouble
  }

  override def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val inputs = List("96942024969", "800813800813", "0", "420", "2435083240587")
    for (i <- inputs) {
      println(s"$i : ${calculateScore(i)}")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: 800813800813 fails because the "800813" bonus isnt for _each_ instance, only for _having_ an instance, sorry for the trick lol ;)

Comment: @Joseph Thanks a lot, I have corrected it.

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>114</s> 112 bytes

```ruby
->n{b=0;[/420/,/69/,n[1]?n.reverse: ?a,/(800813.*)+/,/420$/,/69$/].sum{|x|n.scan(x).size*b+=1.0/n.size}.round 1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NYxLDoIwFEXnroIQBvxsX0vBokEWQjoALYkDq2mDQYG11wbC5P5ycvXQfW1f2eNVTV0FlwYzCjjFRYlT1RBRK6TlR2ojz17dpjjkAJxkKI4SRzk2WOEAC2SG5zSPs0Lm1qpwjJB5/GTcJRVBgNXaFqRfg7p7ZLFvr2/8sijdBWXOfXFYp@1/032DPTh4j5RlOfCMMsj5yRf2Dw)